# Prompting for and accepting input in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In a trivia script, how would you enter a fill in the blank question and an answer like the Seinfeld trivia game in Programming for Beginners?

Comment: What have you tried? What concepts have you learned so far? It doesn't help you for someone to just provide the answer; show us what you've tried and where you're stuck, and people will be more willing to give helpful answers.

Answer (score 6):

As well as [`Read-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347685.aspx) you can directly use the [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) class, to read a single character (without needing ENTER):

```
$key = [Console]::ReadKey()
$char = $key.KeyChar
```

Comment: #Ask the player the eighth question
While ($question8 -eq "George"){

  Clear-Host  #clear the windows command console screen

  write-Host
  Write-Host "Fill in the blank"
  Write-Host
  Write-Host "_______is attacked by a hawk."
  Write-Host
  $question8 = Read-Host " Fill in the blank with the correct name" `
    "and press the Enter key"

}


#Clear the Windows command console screen
Clear-Host

Comment: This is what I have tried but no luck I have made some changes to it but can not figure out what I need to impute to get it to work

Comment: @Colby: Please edit the question to include further information (and from the code I expect you needed `-neq` (not equals) in the while condition).

Comment: This works fine *except* in PowerShell ISE.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Read-Host cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347685.aspx) for reading input from the user, and you'll need some [conditional logic](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-tutorial-conditional-logic/) to check against the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Ask the player the seventh question
while (($question7 -eq "")) {

  Clear-Host  #Clear the Windows command console screen

  Write-Host
  Write-Host " What food item did Jerry say Newman wouldn't eat even if it was deep fried in chocolate sauce?"
  Write-Host
  Write-Host " Broccoli"
  Write-Host " Peas"
  Write-Host " Apples"
  Write-Host " Carrots"
  Write-Host
  $question7 = Read-Host " Type the word representing the correct answer" `
    "and press the Enter key"

}
```